# How to connect to SQL Server database in web using client windows credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, windows-authentication

Scenario: instead of using the server Windows credentials to connect to database, I want to use the Windows credentials from which the person is accessing website.

- IIS hosted Server IP:                  : 10.10.10.10
- Website Accessing from client machine  : 10.10.10.11

I want to use the credentials from logged in user of 10.10.10.11 for accessing the database.

Is there any way to do that? I tried searching in google extensively and failed to get a proper answer. Please let me know how to achieve this or give me a lead so as to get this done.

Comment: I would think you would need to set up and use some impersonation (via the web.config) along with the connection string modifier "Integrated Security=true", but I've never done it so I can't offer specific direction.  Maybe that gives you so ideas to start with though.

Comment: I think that integrated Security will only work when the client is on the same Domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the configuration to

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And Go to IIS Server >> Sites >> Website>> Authentication

```
Anonymous Authentication >> Disabled
ASP.Net Impersonation    >> Enabled
Basic Authentication     >> Enabled
Forms Authentication     >> Disabled
Windows Authentication   >> Disabled
```

This will generate a popup for credentials. When credentials are entered, it will be used to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

If using Windows Authentication, you can simply use [Impersonation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/134ec8tc(v=vs.100).aspx) to make the web worker process' current thread use the client's user credentials

In web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

and make the ado.net connection use the same user by adding this property to the connection string (assuming you use SQL Server or any other DBMS supporting this option)

```
Integrated Security=sspi
```